# Keep line breaks with jQuery .text() in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an address filled in `<p>` tag. On click of edit button I turn that `<p>` tag address into `<textarea>` allowing user to edit it. 
but whenever the user clicks on edit, the address text from `<p>` tag is fetched in `<textarea>` without line breaks.

HTML Markup:

```
<a href="" class="editShipAdd">Edit</a>
<a href="" class="saveShipAddBtn">Save</a>
    <table class="table shipping-address-table"> 
                                <tbody> 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="jumbotron custjumbo">
      <p class="datainfo" id="shipping_address">123, Sample Street,<br>
       Sample Sample Road,<br> Bangalore, <br>Karnataka - 123xyz</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

JS code:

```
$(".editShipAdd").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datasets = $('.shipping-address-table>tbody>tr td').find(".datainfo");
    var savebtn = $('.saveShipAddBtn');
    datasets.each(function(){
      var theid   = $(this).attr("id");
      var newid   = theid+"-form";
      var currval = $(this).text().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');

      console.log(currval);

        $(this).html('<textarea  name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value=""
         class="form-control">'+currval+'</textarea>');  
      });

    $(this).css("display", "none");
    savebtn.css("display", "inline-block");
  });

  $(".saveShipAddBtn").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elink   = $(this).prev(".editShipAdd");
    var datasets = $('.shipping-address-table>tbody>tr td').find(".datainfo");
    datasets.each(function(){
      var newid   = $(this).attr("id");
      var einput  = $("#"+newid+"-form");
      var newval  = einput.val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
      console.log(newval);
      einput.remove();
      $(this).html(newval);
    });
     $(this).css("display", "none");
    elink.css("display", "inline-block");
    });
```

To see the problem, I have created a fiddle here [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8jpLuhcn/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. To get line breaks use `$(this).html()` instead of `$(this).text()`.
2. To use the line breaks inside the textarea replace the `<br>` with `&#013;&#010;` which is the ASCII equivalent.

This line:

```
var currval = $(this).text().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Should be:

```
var currval = $(this).html().replace(/<br> ?/g, '&#013;&#010;');
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jpLuhcn/3/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried with &#0013 codes also but I was missing html there. well done.